# get gradle debug logs in a file as opposed to stdout

Tags: gradle

We use gradle from jenkins.  99% of the time, it works, and we really want it to just list the tasks, and get 20 lines of output.  Occasionally it doesn't - and we turn on debug logging, and get 40mb of output.

Is there any way to get both?  What I want to achieve is have the default gradle output, but the equivalent of --debug going to a log file.  Most underlying logging methods support multi-targeting of log levels, so I'm wondering if anyone's found a way of doing that with gradle, so in the jenkins output we just see the 20 lines, and if we want to investigate more, we can just go into the workspace and click on the log file.

Comment: It seems that it's not possible at the moment - the only idea is to write a custom logger (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html) however it does not seem to be what you really need.

Comment: hmmm - that may doi it - I'll investigate... Thankyou!

Comment: ok - plot thickens... it looks like it will be "good enough", will post the solution here when I'm finished - but found a weirdness...  if I paste in the code in the documentation to init.gradle, and run with -I init.gradle - it works great.  If I try to put the same code into build.gradle - it says could not find method useLogger().    Now the documentation clearly says it can be used from the build script.  Anyone know why that doesn't work?  I really don't want to have to tell my users it "it will only work if you run with -I init.gradle"

Comment: I have the same need currently for troubleshooting an issue. My application is using log4j.  I can just temporarily change the applications log4j.properties to have a file appender instead of console.